# How to fetch a specific substring from string?

Tags: c, fetch

In this code, I want to select the second word from the file and the third one also and print that one but I am unable to fetch specific words. I searched a lot and done a lot of stuff to fetch the second and third words from the str variable but unable to do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  char str[] = "bilal,1000,savings";
  char toFind, name[20], account[20]; 
  char * word1;
  char * word2;
  char * word3;
  int i=0, numberOfFields = 3, amount;
  static const char * listing[] = {"Name","Amount","Account"};

  for(i=0; i<numberOfFields; i++){
    printf("%d. Here is your %s \n", i, listing[i]);
  }

  printf("Which one: ");
  scanf("%c", &toFind);

  if(toFind == '0'){
    printf("selected zero\n");
    word1 = strtok(str, ",");
    printf("%s\n", word1);
  }
  else if(toFind == '1'){
    printf("selected one\n");
  }
  else if(toFind == '2'){
    printf("selected two\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you parse each line up front, it makes it simpler:

```
  char str[] = "bilal,1000,savings";
  char *word1 = strtok(str, ",");
  char *word2 = strtok(NULL, ",");
  char *word3 = strtok(NULL, ",");

  printf("Which one: ");
  scanf("%c", &toFind);

  if(toFind == '0'){
    printf("selected zero\n");
    printf("%s\n", word1);
  }
  else if(toFind == '1'){
    printf("selected one\n");
    printf("%s\n", word2);
  }
  else if(toFind == '2'){
    printf("selected two\n");
    printf("%s\n", word3);
  }
```

Comment: You can't keep passing `str` to `strtok`. You have to pass `NULL` on the 2nd and 3rd calls

Comment: @CraigEstey: Whoops. You're completely right. Thanks!